# Elementary probability odds of assigned seating

Tags: probability

So my friend, through randomly assigned seating, is sitting next to his best friend for his final tomorrow. I said that he was very lucky because the chances of that happening are 1/(239!*2!), where there are 240 students in the classroom. Is my claim correct? :)

Comment: You need to specify how the seats are arranged. For example, $120$ tables where each table with $2$ seats, or $80$ tables where each table with $3$ seats can give different answers. But in any case, your answer cannot be correct because (a) if there is always at least one person sitting next to your friend, there are only $239$ different people possibly sitting next to your friend. So the probability your friend's best friend sitting next to your friend is at least $1/239$. (b) If all seats are arranged independently, nobody can sit next to each other. Then obviously the probability is zero.

Comment: Assuming it's a large auditorium, I just imagined to count how many ways the students could be assigned into a row,just walk in and sit.

Comment: You still need to consider two different cases: (1) People who sit beside the wall (they only have $1$ neighbor), and (2) People who do not sit beside the wall (they have $2$ neighbors).

Comment: so something like (240 choose 2) for ways people can be picked for spots without neighbors assuming the first and last people don't have neighbors leaving 237! ways them two can get arranged sitting next to each other?

Comment: While you can find the probability by using (number of combinations satisfying the condition) / (total number of combinations), the numerator and denominator can be very large, making the analysis and calculation too complicated. Please see my answer below, hope it can give you some light on how to tackle the question.

Answer (score 0):

The actual probability can depend on the way the seats are arranged. Let's make the following assumption:

$(1)$ The examination hall is a large auditorium, with seats arranged as a rectangle of $x$ rows and $y$ columns. From the question, the $x \times y = 240$.

$(2)$ All students in column $1$ have only one neighbor (the left side is a wall), and all students in column $y$ have only one neighbor (the right side is a wall). All students in other columns can have two neighbors (one on the left and one on the right).

[image]

The analysis:

**Case $1$**: For the students in column $1$ and column $y$, they have only $1$ neighbor. So if your friend sits in one of these seats, $1$ of the $239$ people will sit next to him/her. So, his/her best friend sitting right next to him/her is $1/239$.

And, the probability your friend sits in one of the seats at column $1$ or column $y$ is = (number of columns next to the wall / total number of columns) = $2/y$.

**Case $2$**: For the students in the other columns, they have $2$ neighbors. So if your friend sits in one of these seats, $2$ of the $239$ people will sit next to him/her. So, his/her best friend sitting right next to him/her is $2/239$.

And, the probability your friend sits in one of the seats at column $2$ to column $(y-1)$ is = (number of columns NOT next to the wall / total number of columns) = $(y-2)/y$.

The overall probability is:

(Probability your friend sits on column $1$ or column $y$ $\times$ Probability his/her best friend sits next)

$+$ (Probability your friend sits on the other columns $\times$ Probability his/her best friend sits next)

= $\frac{2}{y} \times \frac{1}{239} + \frac{y-2}{y} \times \frac{2}{239} $

For instance, if there are $15$ rows and $16$ columns, $y = 16$, then the probability is $0.007845$.